# When printing, does Mac handle converting PDFs to rasters, or does the printer do that?

Tags: pdf, printing

My printer states in its specifications that it supports PostScript 3, PCL 5e/6, PDF, and TIFF. However, several other printers from that manufacturer do not state they support PDF. On the printers that support PDF, does Mac send the PDF file to the printer to be rasterised, and on the non-PDF supporting ones does Mac handle the rasterisation? I am specifically asking about Mac's default print window.

Comment: Which specific printer is this?

Comment: @nohillside Xerox Phaser 6510 (https://www.xerox.co.uk/en-gb/office/printers/phaser-6510).

Comment: You can force the Mac to do the rasterisation, by opening the PDF in Acrobat (Reader), and in the Acrobat print dialog, Advance Print Setup page, you check "print as image", and set the resolution. This will then use Acrobat's rendering engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printers that explicitly support PDF can be sent a stream of PDF data, and the printer will raster it itself.
Printers that support PostScript will be sent a stream of PostScript data.
Printers that support PCL will be sent a stream of PCL data.

The job of printer drivers on your Mac is to tell the Mac which format to use (or in the case of non-native formats like PCL, to convert it).

The MacOS printing system "CUPS" contains programs called things like `cgtops` and `cgtopdf`, which convert CoreGraphics (the internal data structures of the graphical environment) to PS or PDF.

One benefit of the DTP revolution was the printer doing the rasterization from PostScript natively. Non-PS printers back in the day would require software RIPs, like Adobe's PressReady, to do the work, tying up the computer's CPU and producing huge files.

CUPS currently uses PostScript as its default file format, but future versions are planned to use PDF.

Comment: PostScript printers had to be powerful (CPU for running the PostScript program sent, and RAM to hold the raster representation) so they were quite expensive.

Comment: Indeed. But we're well past that now!

Comment: One more question; you say that it is the job of the print driver to tell the Mac what language to use. I did not install a print driver, I simply connected my printer to Wi-Fi and it showed up on my Mac. Will the printer communicate directly to the Mac, acting as it's own driver?

Comment: MacOS can interrogate the printer and then download the correct driver; it may have some standard drivers by default. There's also Apple's own Airprint technology, which is essentially a universal driver.  At the simplest level, a 'driver' is just a file that describes the characteristics of the printer: paper sizes, resolution, duplex options, trays, colour options, and supported file formats.

Answer (score 0):

In usual Xerox fashion what exactly the driver *does* is lost in a morass of technical and legal mumbo jumbo on their website. (Sorry, long history with Xerox)

**But** the printer specifically supports Postscript printing. So we can assume that the driver *sends* Postscript to the printer (likely).

Note that PDF is (basically) a read-only version of Postscript.

Unless what you are printing is already a bitmap then macOS will send Postscript to the printer driver and the driver will likely send postscript to the printer.

In fact NeXTStep (on which macOS was based) used something called "Display Postscript" to draw the screen. MacOS' display output (EG everything you see on your Mac's screen) is put there via the direct ancestor of Display Postscript. So the entire display to print workflow is **ALL** Postscript (or a reasonable facsimile)

Comment: Is there a reference for your last paragraph?

Comment: Please, PDF is NOT a read-only version of PostScript. PDF is its own way to represent a document, and it is (particularly as PDF-X4 and newer) far superior to PostScript.

Comment: It's a tokenised version of PostScript, with some extra bells and whistles.

Comment: @lhf I can't find NeXT docs on line but it was in those documents. I can't find a primary reference. But there are many secondary references on the web e.g. Wikipedia and http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/next.html as well as in the memories of NeXT programmers

Comment: The secondary docs also say that Apple replaced Display Postscript by Quartz (well known) and that Quartz is is based on a subset of the full PDF specs.https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/osx-quartz

Comment: @lhf I found a book authored by Adobe "Programming the Display Postscript System with NeXTSTEP" http://www.kevra.org/TheBestOfNext/BooksArticlesWhitePapers/ProgrammingDisplayPostscript%20/ProgrammingDisplayPostscript%20.html

Comment: From "Programming with Quartz ...." by Gelphman and Laden, 2006.  "Apple created its own graphics library. The Quartz 2D imaging model is based on the PDF imaging model. The PDF imaging model itself is based on the PostScript imaging model."

Comment: We had a couple of NeXT machines at our university (Mathematica made the sale).  The printer was insanely fast (the NeXT did all the work for it)